# I need a sql code that checks that one date field precedes another date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, date

I need a sql code that checks that one date field precedes another date field.How can I write that code I need an example.

Comment: We aren't a code-writing service.  Look somewhere else.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And do you want to do that during a select or do you want to create a constraint that validates the data when inserted?

Comment: Select case when datefield1 < datefield2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  sorry I'm new at this. I,m using a sql server 2014 I want to create a constraint that validates the data when inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select case when datefield1 < datefield2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seem to work

```
use RESERVATIONS
alter table Bookings
add constraint chk_BookinganDepatureDate check(BookingDate<DepartureDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop entering invalid dates . simply make a trigger on that table using below code.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [TriggerName]
       ON  [YourTableName]
AFTER  INSERT
AS 

if exists(select 1 from inserted i where i.DateColumn1>i.DateColumn2)
begin
    rollback
    RAISERROR ('INVALID DATES', 16, 1);
end
```

Or if you want to just compare the dates use simple comparison operator like

> eg:  > or < or =